# Error: CSS only takes effect when words are in visible quotes. Django.

Tags: html, css, django

The body section of the css files works fine, but for some reason, h1 only shows any change when the word 'Sentiment Analysis' is literally in quotes, and these quotes show up on the page. If I take it out of quotes, no changes are reflected on the page.

I am also using Django.

Is there a way to fix this so I don't need quotes showing up on my page if I want to style anything?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>

        <meta charset ="utf-8">
        {% load static %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>'Sentiment Analysis'</h1>
            <hr>
            <a href="/add">Add Stock</a>
        </header>
        <ul>
        The 10 most recently searched stocks:
    {% for scs in sc%}
        <li>{{scs.ticker}} {{scs.points}} {{scs.created_at}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
body {

  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      to top right, 
      #C3E4ED, #00BFFF
    );

}

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have an issue with the h1 already being set somewhere else in the style sheet. Either you can search for it or make your adjustments as important i.e.

> h1 {text-align: center !important;}

Comment: the !important; solved it, it'd be nice to know how to solve this error though in general. h1 is only defined there.